# How to Configure App Engine Multi Class Endpoints

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm currently setting up a project to use app engine with python 2.7 on mac and the new endpoints with a multi class configuration. I believe I'm following the instructions, but when I execute a GET request I receive the following error from wsgi.

```
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

In my app.yaml I have the following configuration.

```
handlers:
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: apis.api
```

In my apis.py I have the following.

```
api = endpoints.api(name="marketplace", version="v1")

@api.api_class(resource_name="system")
class SystemApi(remote.Service):
    @endpoints.method(message_types.VoidMessage, message_types.VoidMessage, path="about", http_method="GET")
    def about(self, request):
        logging.debug("enter")
        return message_types.VoidMessage()

server = endpoints.api_server([api], restricted=False)
```

Then I'm trying to simply perform a get request doing the following.

```
curl http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/marketplace/v1/system/about
```

In which case I receive the following error.

```
Mon, 30 Dec 2013 00:31:33 ERROR    wsgi.py wsgi.Handle:278 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 266, in Handle
    result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
INFO     2013-12-30 00:31:33,710 module.py:617] default: "POST /_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs HTTP/1.1" 500 -
INFO     2013-12-30 00:31:33,710 module.py:617] default: "GET /_ah/api/marketplace/v1/system/about HTTP/1.1" 500 60
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the **last line** in your code for app.yaml:

```
handlers:
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: apis.api
```

to this **last line** to match what you have in your apis.py snippet:

```
handlers:
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: apis.server
```

It's common practice to upper case that particular variable to obviate this particular error.